# Any known pitfalls for integrating spring mvc with angular material

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, angular-material

We are developing an application using Spring MVC and Angular 1.5. We would like to follow Material Design paradigm, so opted for Angular Material. Before going forward I would like to get some expert advice, to see if there are any known issues with this combination (Spring MVC+Angular 1.5 + Angular Material)that we are not aware of.

Thanks for your help in advance!!

Comment: Any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I faced authentication issues with angular material and larvel 5. I was trying to use JWT token based authentication but it was very difficult to keep token alive and angular material is also take more time to create layouts. Although it makes your app supper fast.